# What is the best way to store information within the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

A kernel module I created is constantly generating information that I would like to store within the kernel and be readable from root. I was thinking of storing the information in some sort of log file with specific permissions, but I read that writing to files within the kernel space code is not good.

What is a good way to store information in the kernel that is fast and accessible by root?

~Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's constantly generating *new* information, I would write it out with `printk()`. This way it will be seen by `dmesg` as well be written out to `/var/log/kern.log`.

Although, this is not for sensitive information, since `dmesg` could be used by any user.

Depending on the type of information, you can also provide it via `/proc` or `/sys` files, `netlink`, `relayfs`, `/dev ioctl`.

Comment: Is there another way besides printk()?

Comment: @Irlanco Since I don't know the type and amount of your information, I can't really say. See my edited answer, though.

Comment: It's just strings. Proc is not a persistent way to store information correct?

Comment: @irlanco Every information stored somewhere in the kernel is lost on crash or reboot. You need some userspace program to constantly read the `/proc`, `/sys`, `ioctl`, `relayfs`, `netlink`, ... and write it to disk or store it somewhere permanently.

Comment: @OlafDietsche - actually, information stored within the kernel is not always lost on crash or reboot.  Provided that dynamic memory continues to be refreshed and there has been no intentional zeroing of memory, it is often possible to recover the previous kernel ring buffer upon reboot or from a bootloader - which can be quite useful when debugging.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, on a hardware level that's correct. But I doubt, that you're able to recover this information in a module after the linux kernel has booted, no matter how match voodoo or black art you employ :-)

Comment: @OlafDietsche - actually, you are, by having the kernel routinely copy such leftovers someplace safe early in the boot process, on the chance that they might be interesting.

Comment: `/sysfs/` has a file-size limit of one page - usually 4kB - so this might limit what you can do with it.   To add to the nice long list of options above, you could also implement this a file in `/dev/`